# What is the meaning of esi0a in Assembly insttructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, cheat-engine

I've spent about 6 hours debugging some code using Cheat Engine. I've come across something really weird.

[image: crazy weird instruction]

The instruction reads:

```
imul esi,esi0A
```

What does this mean?

ESI = 5 before the instruction
After the imul instruction it becomes 32.

Comment: Well, `0x0A` = 10, and 5 times 10 is 50 = `0x32`...

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why we have esi twice? Shouldn't it have been just esi,0a?

Comment: No, since `imul` with an immediate constant must specify both the source and destination registers, per the Intel SDM.

Comment: Then shouldn't it be imul esi,esi,0a? There's a comma missing. Anyhow, my question is answered. Would you like to post this as an answer so that I can mark it as complete? I think it'll be helpful for anyone else looking through nuances of cheat-engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The instruction in question was probably intended to be

> `imul esi, esi, 0x0A`

, but Cheat Engine probably forgot to print the comma `,`.

---

#### Longer Version

The mathematical result you describe is consistent with `0x00000005` = 5 being multiplied by `0x0A` = 10 to produce `0x00000032` = 50.

The Intel Software Developers' Manual, Volume 2A, §3.2 - `IMUL - Signed Multiply` documents the instruction's function and valid forms. Of the ones that allow immediate constants, the only available forms require specifying 1) the destination register, 2) the source register and 3) the immediate constant.

In this particular case, obviously these were intended to be respectively `esi`, `esi`, `0x0A`. Cheat Engine only printed it incorrectly.

> [image: IMUL Instruction Forms]